# Make Postgres identifiers case sensitive without quoting

Tags: mysql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I'm trying to migrate a legacy MySQL database into Postgres using Pgloader. I'm trying to think of a relatively robust way to find a way to convert the existing SQL queries to work with the new database with the least amount of manual modifications.

One of the big pain points is that the old database is written in mixed case, and so are all the SQL queries. If you query `SELECT Table.Column` Postgres will treat that as `select table.column` so it doesn't work out of the box. Converting the database tables and columns to lowercase is not an option.

Of course one option would be to manually add quotes around each identifier in all of the queries eg `SELECT "Table"."Column", but I'm wondering if there's another way that I haven't thought of, like a Postgres module or something.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: No, not possible - and it would violate the SQL standard.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but why should that not work? The pgqsl command line interface(And the java jdbc driver, but I don't know how you interface with the db) will accept any case for table and columns. So select TaBLE.colUMN does work.

Comment: @MTilsted It will accept any case, but treat it as lowercase, which I don't want.

Comment: The relevant part is the SQL92 specification, section 5.2 syntax rules contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: Good question, but I think PostgreSQL follows the SQL Standard quite closely. InnoDB (I would assume this is the engine you are coming from) uses case-sensitive identifiers, depending on the OS it's installed on.

Comment: In the short term, you could convert all queries to use `"`. However, in the long term it's better to normalize the table names once and for all. Typing queries would be less error-prone if the database has simple identifiers.

Comment: To amplify comments by @MTilsted and The Impaler, you could change the table and field names to lowercase, but leave the queries intact. If this scenario, the query SELECT Table.Column would work just fine. In fact, in my own databases, I always have lowercase table and field names. But when I go to do queries, I often add capital letters for readability.

Comment: Perhaps a good place to start would be [Migrate your Mindset](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/). If yo do not use double quotes on table and/or column names when you `create table` then *referencing by any case is exactly the same* So `Table.Column` and `TABLE.COLUMN`  and even `TaBLe.COLumn`  **will all** be processed as *table.column*